# How is time complexity of the code Θ(nLogn)?

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, time-complexity, big-o

```
 int n;
 int i, j, k = 0;
    for (i  = n/2; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = 2; j <= n; j = j * 2) {
            k = k + n/2;
        }
    }
```

Just need to calculate the time complexity of the code snippet and the answer is Θ(nLogn) but can you explain how it is Θ(nLogn)

Comment: So you have all of the info. Why can't you calculate?

Comment: Your hint is it is not O(n!)  But seriously, if you cannot figure it out via examination, put some printf calls in there to track how often it is called and see if you cannot find the pattern yourself as you change the loop size?

Comment: "...can you explain how it is Θ(nLogn)" - can you explain how it could be anything *but*  Θ(nLogn)?

Comment: Outer loop is N/2 (or just N).  Inner loop counts by powers of 2 or log base 2 (n).  NLog(N)  Yes?  (Answer because he's taken enough grief...)

Comment: hint: How much times does the internal loop run? (You are lucky - It is costant for every `i`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really not that difficult.

The outer loop runs `n/2` times. That is `O(n)` complexity.

The inner loop again depends on `n` only. It doesn't depend on the `i` from the first loop. So for the complexity of the inner loop we can ignore completely the outer loop. How fortunate!. `j` multiples each time by `2` so we have `logarithm base 2`. That is `O(log(n))`.

The loops are nested so we multiply, thus ending with:

```
O(n log(n))
```